# Change Wordpress theme on theme-broken installation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a Wordpress theme for a client, and I've done a mistake that caused the Wordpress to show the classic error page "There has been a critical error on your website". It's very simple to fix this when you have some advanced access to the server (like an FTP, SSH, cPanel, web-based file manager or something else). But, in this case, I don't have any other access than wp-admin!

I've asked my client for some access (FTP, cPanel or any other), but he don't have any other access too.

So, thinking a bit, I still logged in on this Wordpress (cookies are set), and I'm trying to change the theme from URL (I know the Twenty Twenty One theme is installed). So, I copied the URL that activates the Twenty Twenty One theme from my localhost, changed the domain to match the domain of broken website, and picked up a nonce from DevTools. The final URL is like this:

`http://dev.example.com/wp-admin/themes.php?action=activate&stylesheet=twentytwentyone&_wpnonce=5f324abc99`

Tried to access this from my logged-in browser and... Won't work :( It shows the "There has been a critical error on your website" message.

So, I'm here to ask you... There's another way to change the Wordpress theme outside the panel on a theme-broken installation?

Thank you for all!

Comment: Since you have error already inplace you cant swap theme like that. If you have access to the database there you can override active theme. Honestly avoid clients like this. You cant make a good theme with the theme editor from the admin panel...

Answer (score 0):

Good day, mate.
I see its a common problem when you install Plugin
or theme and everything crash(

If you can not have access to FTP or Cpanel, try to Reinstall WP.
It will delete all themes and refresh the plugins.
After that you can upload and install new themes and website will work.

Go to Dashboard, click Updates and find Re-Install Wordpress button.

Tell please of it helps you...

[image]

Comment: But, when I reinstall WP, it will lose all my data (uploads, database), or not? And, in this case, when I try to access /wp-admin or anything inside /wp-admin, website is showing the critical error message.

Comment: Good day Raphael. Just checked on my local Wordrpress and Reinstall just install Fresh version of wordpress and DO NOT delete plugins, comments and pages.  If you want to delete all the stuff we have some plugins called "wordpress reset". But in your case just try to understand what cause the problem. Here is good article on your question https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website/